# File inside resource cannot find local file

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick, resource-file

I have a project with several `QML` files. All of them are inside resource file. Now I want to load external image, from local file system. But I cannot find a way to do that.

```
Image {
    source: "images/image.png" // that tries to load file as 'qrc:/images/image.png'
    source: "file://images/image.png" // that does not work (file not found)
}
```

So now I'm a bit confused, how can I load the file in right way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The QML engine assumes that relative paths addressed in QML files stored in the Qt Resource System are resolved within that resource file. So if your QML file is in a resource and you want to access a file in the application directory path you should set the path from c++ :

```
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("applicationPath", "file://"+qApp->applicationDirPath()+ "/");
```

Now you can address the file in QML :

```
Image {
    source: applicationPath + "images/image.png"
}
```

Comment: I discovered this recently, and this is the correct answer. I'd also suggest linking to http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-url.html and quoting it: "A relative URL is resolved relative to the URL of the containing component." You say that "all relative paths in QML should also be resolved within that resource file", but it's a bit misleading, because it's not just specific to resource files.

Comment: Thanks @Nejat. Mainly I was looking for a solution with only QML but as I see it's impossible to set up a url relative to app from resourse.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for this post. I worked on this code and saw that it didn't work for me. I finally realized where the problem was. Just use **/** instead of **//**.

```
context->setContextProperty("applicationPath","file:/"+qApp->applicationDirPath()+"/");
```